# How to specify a custom attribute sort order using XSLT in VB.NET (VS2008)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, visual-studio-2008

I have a schema like this:

[image]

XML:

```
<Shipment> <Destination City='New York'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='B' ProductType='THI'></Product> <Product ProductCode='U' ProductType='SIS'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='JUS'></Product> <Product ProductCode='G' ProductType='TMA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='DEU'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='POK'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='London'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='C' ProductType='MAK'></Product> <Product ProductCode='H' ProductType='ESN'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='OSE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='NSE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='ATA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='Y' ProductType='LLL'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='Paris'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='B' ProductType='WHO'></Product> <Product ProductCode='A' ProductType='WAT'></Product> <Product ProductCode='G' ProductType='CHE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='STH'></Product> <Product ProductCode='L' ProductType='WAT'></Product> <Product ProductCode=' ' ProductType='CHM'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='Munich'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='Q' ProductType='ENN'></Product> <Product ProductCode='U' ProductType='THE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='I' ProductType='SHA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='C' ProductType='DOW'></Product> <Product ProductCode='H' ProductType='KNO'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='WSS'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> </Shipment>
```

And I need it to sort on Product Code within each delivery so the output is thus:

[image]

XML:

```
<Shipment> <Destination City='New York'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='JUS'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='POK'></Product> <Product ProductCode='B' ProductType='THI'></Product> <Product ProductCode='U' ProductType='SIS'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='DEU'></Product> <Product ProductCode='G' ProductType='TMA'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='London'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='NSE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='ATA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='C' ProductType='MAK'></Product> <Product ProductCode='H' ProductType='ESN'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='OSE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='Y' ProductType='LLL'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='Paris'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='B' ProductType='WHO'></Product> <Product ProductCode='A' ProductType='WAT'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='STH'></Product> <Product ProductCode='L' ProductType='WAT'></Product> <Product ProductCode=' ' ProductType='CHM'></Product> <Product ProductCode='G' ProductType='CHE'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='Munich'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='Q' ProductType='ENN'></Product> <Product ProductCode='U' ProductType='THE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='I' ProductType='SHA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='C' ProductType='DOW'></Product> <Product ProductCode='H' ProductType='KNO'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='WSS'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> </Shipment>
```

Product Code is either a letter or blank. The following rules apply:

1. Product Code R should appear first
2. Product Code G should appear last
3. Anything else is in between

I've never used XSLT in anger before and it has been a long time since I did any VB.NET so in the name of getting something working, I came up with the following.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        ' The document
        Dim document As String = "<Shipment> <Destination City='New York'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='B' ProductType='THI'></Product> <Product ProductCode='U' ProductType='SIS'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='JUS'></Product> <Product ProductCode='G' ProductType='TMA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='DEU'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='POK'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='London'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='C' ProductType='MAK'></Product> <Product ProductCode='H' ProductType='ESN'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='OSE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='NSE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='R' ProductType='ATA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='Y' ProductType='LLL'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='Paris'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='B' ProductType='WHO'></Product> <Product ProductCode='A' ProductType='WAT'></Product> <Product ProductCode='G' ProductType='CHE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='STH'></Product> <Product ProductCode='L' ProductType='WAT'></Product> <Product ProductCode='S' ProductType='CHM'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> <Destination City='Munich'> <Delivery> <Product ProductCode='Q' ProductType='ENN'></Product> <Product ProductCode='U' ProductType='THE'></Product> <Product ProductCode='I' ProductType='SHA'></Product> <Product ProductCode='C' ProductType='DOW'></Product> <Product ProductCode='H' ProductType='KNO'></Product> <Product ProductCode='E' ProductType='WSS'></Product> </Delivery> </Destination> </Shipment>  "

        ' Load it
        Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        xDoc.LoadXml(DirtyHack(document))

        ' Required for string output
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb)

        ' Do the transformation
        Dim tranny As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()
        tranny.Load("c:\sandbox\MassageXML\Autobots.xslt")
        tranny.Transform(xDoc, writer)

        ' See what mess we've made
        Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString)

    End Sub

    Function DirtyHack(ByVal inputString As String) As String

        Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        dict.Add("ProductCode='", "SortOrder='2' ProductCode='")
        dict.Add("SortOrder='2' ProductCode='R'", "SortOrder='1' ProductCode='R'")
        dict.Add("SortOrder='2' ProductCode='G'", "SortOrder='3' ProductCode='G'")

        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dict
            inputString = inputString.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
        Next

        Return inputString

    End Function

End Module
```

In essence, I add another attribute on the fly, sort by this and then remove it but I'm sure there must be a cleaner way. Any ideas?

This is the XSLT script such as it is so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@SortOrder" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Delivery">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="@SortOrder" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please post the XML input as a code snippet? Otherwise it is hard to suggest some tested code as there is no input data to test. I think you should be able to define the sort order in the XSLT, without needing to manipulate the XML input first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, it defines a mapping of product codes to numeric sort values as a parameter and selects that in the `xsl:sort`, the only drawback is that in XSLT 1.0 you need `exsl:node-set` or `msxsl:node-set` to convert the result tree fragment that the parameter is into a node set to be able to use it as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl exsl"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="sort-map-rtf">
      <map pc="R" sort="1"/>
      <map pc="G" sort="3"/>
      <map pc="*" sort="2"/>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="sort-map" select="exsl:node-set($sort-map-rtf)/map"/>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Delivery">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="($sort-map[@pc = current()/@ProductCode] | $sort-map[@pc = '*'])[1]/@sort" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38ZM.

Comment: Superb - thank you. I shall look into **exsl:node-set**